# POST /tasks/:id/delete

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have just started to try to work with the play framework and tried to work with todolist project

in the route file:
i have no problem with other things but the following 
POST    /tasks/ :id/delete          controllers.application.deleteTask()
what is the exact job of :id/delete 
if anybody help me 
please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 segments in your sample splited by slash. first is `tasks` and it's static, second is `:id` - it is dynamic, and third, again static is `delete` that means that link can be `/tasks/1/delete`, or `/tasks/2/delete` etc. Anyway you should pass this dynamic segment as a param of `deleteTask()` action:

```
POST /tasks/:id/delete controllers.application.deleteTask(id: Long)
```

it's described in [routes documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaRouting) in **Dynamic parts** and **Parameter types** sections.